# Nginx autoindex format based on value of Accept header

Tags: nginx

I'd like to set `autoindex_format` value (`html`, `xml`, `json`) according to value of `Accept` HTTP header received in a request.

I've tried to do that with map, but get `emerg` during start Nginx:

```
nginx: [emerg] invalid value "$autoindex_type" in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

```
http {
    ...
    map $http_accept $autoindex_type {
        default html;
        ~json json;
        ~xml xml;
    }
    ...
    location / {
        root /usr/share/nginx/files;
        autoindex on;
        autoindex_format $autoindex_type;
    }
}
```

Could somebody advise what proper way to set value for `autoindex_format` according to `Accept` value of HTTP request in Nginx?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many Nginx directives do not accept variables as a parameter. Those that do should explicitly mention it.

There is a way. You would need to place each `autoindex_format` statement within its own `location` block. The three `location` blocks would use *fake* URLs and then translate them to the correct pathname using `alias`.

For example:

```
map $http_accept $autoindex_type {
    default html;
    ~json   json;
    ~xml    xml;
}

server {
    ...

    location / {
        rewrite ^ /$autoindex_type$uri last;
    }
    location /html/ {
            alias /usr/share/nginx/files/;
            autoindex on;
            autoindex_format html;
    }
    location /json/ {
            alias /usr/share/nginx/files/;
            autoindex on;
            autoindex_format json;
    }
    location /xml/ {
            alias /usr/share/nginx/files/;
            autoindex on;
            autoindex_format xml;
    }
}
```

In the example above, the *fake* URLs use the prefixes `/html/`, `/json/`, and `/xml/` - but you may wish to obfuscate them to avoid a potential collision with real URLs within your system.

---

I know you have already accepted the above answer, but I wanted to add a second example that uses *named locations* instead of *fake* URLs, and therefore also avoids the use of `alias`. It uses an (undocumented) feature of Nginx which allows named locations to be specified in a variable.

For example:

```
map $http_accept $autoindex_type {
    default @html;
    ~json   @json;
    ~xml    @xml;
}

server {
    ...

    root /usr/share/nginx/files;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $autoindex_type;
    }
    location @html {
            autoindex on;
            autoindex_format html;
    }
    location @json {
            autoindex on;
            autoindex_format json;
    }
    location @xml {
            autoindex on;
            autoindex_format xml;
    }
}
```

`try_files` requires at least two parameters, and the named location must be the last parameter. In the example `$uri` is used as the first parameter. To prevent `try_files` taking its *file* action, specify a *fake* filename such as `try_files nonexistent $autoindex_type;`

Comment: Thanks for the answer! By some reason on GET request of / location I get response 404.

Comment: Ah, it looks like I missed trailing slash in `alias`.

Comment: Richard, thanks for second example! I'll try it as well.